# Microsoft Access - Using the In Clause in a Query over a Network

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

So right now, we have a setup where ui.mdb and database.mdb are two separate access files. I am querying the database using the IN clause (ie "SELECT * FROM USERS IN 'DB\example_db.mdb'") and it works great on my local machine. The problem is that people are accessing the file over a public share in the network (ie "\computername\example_ui.mdb"). Once people try to use that query with the IN clause, they get the error:

c:\users\username\documents\db\example_db.mdb is not a valid path. Make sure the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

I did some research and I found this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167452, but frankly, I don't really understand it. Does anyone have any familiarity with solving this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a full path, not a partial one. If you are 100% sure that everybody in the company has the same mappings, you can use comething like `IN "X:\myFOlder\myFile.mdb"`.
This is using a mapping.
If mapping is not reliable, you can state a full absolute address using UNC (Universal Naming Convention):  `IN '\\MyServer\myShare\myFolder\myFile.mdb'`

Comment: The quotes seem to be required with a UNC path.  Without them I get "Syntax error in FROM clause".  Actually, seems to be same with a standard Windows drive letter path.

Comment: Damn you are 100% correct on both accounts. How annoying, does this mean I'm going to have to have to update the code to production's path before deployment?

Comment: Depending on where you need it, you could eventually use CurrentDb.Name to dynamically build the "IN" path.

Comment: That's a bit too much, but glad to help  ;-)

Comment: Or you could store the path in a local "config" table, if you're building SQL statements in code.